# How to change the font size of J2ME command text?

Tags: java-me, lcdui

I want to reduce the `font size` of the `Command` text. How to achieve that ?

Comment: Hi Pheromix, are you using plain Java ME or any GUI like LWUIT or Polish ?

Comment: The `Command` is a Java ME Command.

Comment: In Pure Java ME, I am not sure if its possible or not. I am using J2ME Polish for UI. Here I can set Command Button's Size in Polish.css file. Sorry I am not aware in Pure Java ME Application

Comment: You might be able to change the font size on the device and sometimes (but not always) this will be picked up by the java implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MIDP 2 has no API that would allow to reduce the font size of the `lcdui Command` text (label).

Full list of available methods is provided in [lcdui Command API documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/javax/microedition/lcdui/Command.html) - one can easily find out that there is nothing about fonts there